# Join tables from differents DB

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite

I would like to do an outer join between two tables from differents DB.

**TABLE 1**

```
    A    B   
---------------
    1    5
    2    8
    3    3
    4    7
```

**TABLE 2**

```
    A    C   
---------------
    1    11
    2    nan
    3    52
    4    7
```

**TABLE 3**

```
    A    B    C   
--------------------
    1    5    11
    2    8    nan
    3    3    52
    4    7    7
```

The problem is that I have two databases, with only one DB it will be as simple as :

```
select TABLE1.A, TABLE1.B, TABLE2.C
from TABLE1 as TABLE1
left outer join TABLE2 as TABLE2
    on TABLE1.A = TABLE2.A
```

How can I do it with two DB connections and two cursors? I'm using SQLite3 and Python 2.7

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `attach` keyword in SQLite3 to attach databases together.

```
attach 'database1.db' as db1;
attach 'database2.db' as db2;
```

You should then be able to do your left outer join

```
select
  *
from
  db1.TABLE1 a
    left outer join 
  db2.TABLE2 b on b.SomeColumn = a.SomeColumn;
```

You can see all connected databases with keyword

```
.databases
```